# MFA Provider for ASP .NET Web Forms with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I'm looking for a good MFA provider to be incorporated to a legacy Web Forms application that uses Forms Authentication for security. It seems most of the MFA providers I see (such as Authy) are built around ASP .NET Identity. I'm trying to look for a solution that doesn't scratch the legacy application much... migrating the legacy application to ASP .NET Identity will be a nightmare. I've tried looking into Authy, Auth0, PingID and Okta and they all seem to be overkill for our use case. I'm trying to find an MFA provider that can work alongside Forms Authentication.

Comment: maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-web-forms-app-with-sms-two-factor-authentication? Or simply create your own 2 factor authentication, like using the Google Authenticator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use https://www.twilio.com/ for my MFA. I am only using the SMS functionality though, so essentially you need to hook up their sms code with your form authentication process. The only difference is that you don't have the identity component (which I highly suggest that you implement). Check out the C# code here for more info on the SMS API procedure: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/csharp-dotnet-framework.

I understand that the following is for MVC, but you can convert the code to Web Forms as well: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/two-factor-authentication-csharp-mvc. 
The above example also uses the identity framework, but just take a look at the implementation of using SMS and you can migrate the concept into your web form.